Pop up menu in lower left hand corner does not show when adding a mesh or any other action
Using blender 4.1 The pop menu in the lower LH corner does not display when I add a mesh, or say , go to add a bevel in edit mode.  I can access the menu by using F9 (adjust last operation) but that's a real pain.  It only happens on one file, and only occurred half way through building it.  Fingers crossed someone will tell me now dub I am!.

Hello, Ed, welcome to BSE. This looks very likely to be a duplicate, as Chris has suggested. If the link works for you, we'd really appreciate it if you told us so, here in the comments. Thanks.

Found the solution - I'd unchecked the  'Adjust Last Operation' tick box in the view menu. All is good. Blood pressure normal.
